# How to deal with the error libXdamage.so.1: cannot open shared object file on Centos VM?

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, rpm

Running a Java program got the exception:

```
Caused by:
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. 
Firefox console output:\nXPCOMGlueLoad error for file 
/home/anarinsky/.alternator/browsers/firefox/libxul.so:
libXdamage.so.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.\n
```

Assumed that this exception is due to the absence of installed libXdamage.so.1, so I downloaded rpm libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl.rpm, but installation:

```
rpm -ivh libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl.rpm
```

resulted in the following error:

```
    warning: libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 

    Signature, key ID 429476b4: NOKEY
    error: Failed dependencies:

ld-linux-armhf.so.3 is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
ld-linux-armhf.so.3(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libX11.so.6 is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libXfixes.so.3 is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libc.so.6 is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.5) is needed by libXdamage-1.1.4-12.fc28.armv7hl
```

Started from installing libX11 but got the failed dependencies again

Is it possible to install all packages at once?  Or maybe to download a Centos VM that already contains all packages? If the 2nd way is possible , please provide the URL for downloading.

Comment: Install libXdamage : `# yum install libXdamage` . Anyway, a Fedora 28 pagkage won't do for CentOS http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

Comment: @Knud, you can put this as answer, I will accept, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the *package* providing libXdamage.so.1: `# yum provides */libXdamage.so.1`

Install libXdamage :

```
# yum install libXdamage
```

Anyway, a Fedora 28 pagkage won't do for CentOS http://mirror.centos.org/centos/

( And it doesn't seem like you have an OS for "armv7hl" processor. Hence the dependencies.)